# How do i move sidebar-wrapper below horizontal bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am giving a try as new am new to html and css can you guys suggest how can I move side wrapper below a horizontal nav bar and the nav bar should fit into page width. in horizontal nav bar I have text called home and logout can you guys move right end side and make it as homepage icon and logout icon

Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/xzm7bx4n/

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.row{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    height: 100%
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -150px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 200px; 
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
 float:top;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar_menu li a, .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: #252525;
    border-top: 1px solid #373737;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar_name {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#main_icon
{
    float:right;
   padding-right: 65px;
   padding-top:20px;
}
.sub_icon
{
    float:right;
   padding-right: 65px;
   padding-top:10px;
}
.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 70px;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper" class="active">  
    <!-- Sidebar -->
            <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">       
        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
          <li><a>New Project</a></li>           
          <li><a>Projects</a></li>
          <li><a>Pyramid Oppurtinities</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
        <div class="page-content inset">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-14">
              <p class="well lead">SANRIA  Home   Logout</p>
     
     
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row"> <!-- div da esquerda -->
                    <!-- Text input CNPJ e Razao Social-->

                </div> <!-- fim div da esquerda -->
            </div>
             <!--  <p class="well lead">An Experiment using the sidebar (<a href="http://animeshmanglik.name">animeshmanglik.name</a>)</p>  -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you asked this question. When you have a header that should be the first thing in the DOM, you want to put this  or  as the first item inside the wrapper. The sidebar element can be placed below it to achieve a sleek look. 
If you wanted a different style, we can discuss that as well.
This is the code I ended with.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="active">  
    <!-- Sidebar -->
            <!-- Sidebar -->

      <!-- Page content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
        <div class="page-content inset">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-14">
            <p class="well lead">SANRIA  Home   Logout</p>


            <div class="container">
              <div class="row"> <!-- div da esquerda -->
                  <!-- Text input CNPJ e Razao Social-->

              </div> <!-- fim div da esquerda -->
          </div>
             <!--  <p class="well lead">An Experiment using the sidebar (<a href="http://animeshmanglik.name">animeshmanglik.name</a>)</p>  -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="sidebar-wrapper">       
            <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
              <li><a>New Project</a></li>           
              <li><a>Projects</a></li>
              <li><a>Pyramid Oppurtinities</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is CSS.

```
.row{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#wrapper {
    /*padding-left: 70px;*/
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    height: 100%
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -150px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 200px;   
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
     /*float:top;*/
}

.sidebar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
    /*padding-left: 150px;*/
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar_menu li a, .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: #252525;
    border-top: 1px solid #373737;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar_name {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#main_icon
{
    float:right;
   padding-right: 65px;
   padding-top:20px;
}
.sub_icon
{
    float:right;
   padding-right: 65px;
   padding-top:10px;
}
.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
#wrapper {
    /*padding-left: 70px;*/
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 70px;
}
#wrapper.active {
    /*padding-left: 150px;*/
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
}

.well{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.lead{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
p{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eq6bhyg5/

Notes: I took out all of the unnecessary padding that seemed to be throwing off the view. 
We really should use the space that we are given. 
If you want the sidebar to be in the side, with the page including header next to it, adjacent.
Action: Take the sidebar back out of the page-content-wrapper. 
add `display:inline-block; width:20%` to side-bar css. Then set the wrapper css to `width: 80%; display: inline-block;`

Comment: Thanks, can you tell how do I move home and logout to right end

Comment: You can wrap: `<div><span>home</span> <span>logout</span></div>` Then apply in css: `.outer_div_class{text-align: right}` With these other spans you can further diversify the styles in your home and logout sections.